# Typescript generic type array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, interface, typescript-generics

I've got the following method:

```
getFiveObjectsFromArray(array: T[]) {
    return array.slice(0, 5);
  }
```

I'm using this method a few times, is there any why using Typscript to pass a generic argument instand of using multiple types?

By the way, when i'm trying use parameter 'T' i've got this error:

> "TS7006: Parameter 'T' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely make this generic. Have you tried? Can you show us your attempt please? Where are you stuck? Look at the type declaration of `slice` itself for inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to accept any `Array` **without minding** the `Type` of it,

```js
function getFiveObjectsFromArray(array: unknown[]) {
    return array.slice(0, 5);
}
```

If you want to use `Generic`, Then

```js
function getFiveObjectsFromArray<T>(array: T[]) {
    return array.slice(0, 5);
}

getFiveObjectsFromArray<number>([0]);
getFiveObjectsFromArray<string>(["hello"]);

getFiveObjectsFromArray<string>([0]); // shows error
```

Comment: when im using unknown i got the following error: TS2322: Type 'unknown[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.

Comment: but the 'Generic' way works great thanks! I've miss the diamond part: <T>

Comment: @NaorYael if this answers your question mark it as answer